# NGINX Multiple location using the same SSL client certificate to the backend server

Tags: nginx

`Hello All of you,
Newbee quetion.
I trying to simplify my config. I'm using TLS_MA (mutual authentication) between NGINX and my backend servers where different micro_service are hosted. I'm using the same client certificate for all the services.
Each services are defined by a location on NGINX. My question is how can i configure my proxy_SSL_* only once for all the locations in place of each time repeating the same proxy_ssl config for every locations ? Thx guys.

Here is my config -> i would like to simplify it. Since i'm using the same Client certificate for all the services, how can i make only one proyx_ssl_*  for all the service ? `

```
location /toto {  
        proxy_ssl_session_reuse on;  
        proxy_ssl_verify on;  
    proxy_redirect off;  
        proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/backend-server-cert.pem;  
        proxy_ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/server-cert.pem;  
        proxy_ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server-key.pem;  
        proxy_http_version 1.1;  
        proxy_pass https://servcies1.domaine.com;  
 }  

location /tata {  
        proxy_ssl_session_reuse on;  
        proxy_ssl_verify on;  
    proxy_redirect off;  
        proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/backend-server-cert.pem;  
        proxy_ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/server-cert.pem;  
        proxy_ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server-key.pem;  
        proxy_http_version 1.1;  
        proxy_pass https://servcies2.domaine.com/;    
}  

location /titi {  
        proxy_ssl_session_reuse on;  
        proxy_ssl_verify on;  
    proxy_redirect off;  
        proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/backend-server-cert.pem;  
        proxy_ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/server-cert.pem;  
        proxy_ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server-key.pem;  
        proxy_http_version 1.1;  
        proxy_pass https://servcies3.domaine.com/;  
}
```